# Young boy thought lost returns... or does he?

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie is about a family of 5, a dad and mom, 3 children - 2 brothers and 1 sister. I think the Dad is some sort of a politician.
It can also be he was major I'm not sure.

So there was an event in the streets and there was a lot of people there. The older brother and sister were supposed to looks after the little brother but then they Lost him.

The movie then switches to some years later, I can't remember How many but the little boy was now a teenager. He walks into a police station pointing at a picture of him and said he was that boy.

When he comes home the family is thrilled to have him back, except the older brother. I remember a scene where the older brother says the little brother is not who he says he is because he eats eggs. Apparently he hated eggs when he was younger.

I also remember when the police asked if he could see anything from where he was held, and he said every morning he could see a dragon.

The language is English, and I don't remember the release or when I watched it, and the event was in a Big City perhaps NY, I'm not really sure but a Big city. But I'm almost 100% sure it's a movie.

Comment: Hi! Some more details would be greatly appreciated. Like: Do you remember the country\language? The approximate year of release and when you saw it? And if it was *really* a movie [Because, er, I happen to know it isn't ;)]?

Comment: The language is english, and i dont remeber The release or when i watch it, and i The event was in a Big City perhaps NY im not really sure but a Big city. But im almost 100% sure its a movie

Comment: But Hey, if you are sure its a serie you are Welcome do give me a name. I will instantly know if its The right movie/serie

Comment: The moral of the story: Don’t ever let your children leave home! And if they change when they come back? What that there is… SATAN!

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like this is actually the ABC show [The Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Family_(2016_TV_series)) that ran for one season in 2016.

> The series stars Joan Allen as Claire Warren, the ambitious and manipulative mayor of the fictional city Red Pines, Maine, and matriarch of the Warren family, who announces her candidacy for governor when her son Adam, played by Liam James, returns after having been kidnapped 10 years prior.

His sibling knows it isn't him because he likes eggs all of a sudden. And he says he saw a dragon, breathing fire right at him. Perhaps you just saw the pilot. See if the preview rings any bells:

Comment: Thats it is. Now i remeber i watched it on tv but i only saw 1 episode so i assumed it was a movie. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshRømer Glad to help! :) Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, this effectively resolves your question. And welcome to M&TV!